# Query run result in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I am running below query in Teradata editor:

```
SELECT 'EMP_INFO_MAIN' as TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) as RECORD_COUNT FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP_SAL' as TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) as RECORD_COUNT FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPARTMENT_INFO' as TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) as RECORD_COUNT FROM SCHEMA.TABLE3;
```

The query is giving me below result:

```
TABLE_NAME  | RECORD_COUNT
------------|------------- 
EMP_INFO    | 10 
EMP_SAL     | 11 
DEPARTME    | 110
```

The first column is not showing complete table name.
Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue.

In Teradata the first SELECT of a UNION determines the resulting data typ and the column name, so either change the order of SELECTs to start with the longest name or add a CAST in the 1st SELECT:

```
SELECT CAST('EMP_INFO_MAIN' AS VARCHAR(20)) as TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) as RECORD_COUNT FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP_SAL' as TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) as RECORD_COUNT FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPARTMENT_INFO' as TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) as RECORD_COUNT FROM SCHEMA.TABLE3;
```